# Is it possible to use the by variable from the left and right dataframes separately after a left_join procedure

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

After joining two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) I would like to flag in column `check` which `id`s are in `df1` but not `df2` (example below).

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3))

df2 <-
  data.frame(id = c(1, 2))

df3 <-
  left_join(df1, df2)
```

Required result

```
  id check
1  1     Y
2  2     Y
3  3     N
```

I can achieve the result using a temp column (example below)

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3))

df2 <-
  data.frame(id = c(1, 2), temp = "Y")

df3 <-
  left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(check = ifelse(is.na(temp), "N", "Y")) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

but I was hoping for a solution where a temp column isn't required, I've tried some different approaches (for example below), but haven't been able to find a better solution.

```
df3 <-
  left_join(x = df1, y = df2) %>%
  mutate(check = ifelse(is.na(y.id), "N", "Y"))
```

but this errors with...

```
Joining, by = "id"
Error: object 'y.id' not found
```

Comment: `df3$id %in% df2$id`?

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of this